# Change Class of Menu in Master Page Dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can i Change the CSS Class name of menu which is in Master page from
Child Page?
I want to change class to "active", when any of child form of menu is open,

Is any C# or JavaScript Code available?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the code you have written so far please?

Comment: i have menu like <ul><li class='active'>Home.... <li>Masters ..</li><ul><li>State</li><li>City</li>.. I want to set Active to Masters when city or state form is open..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By understanding your question, i think you want to change the class of the li or whatever tag that is used in menu when the page changes.

Please add the following c# code under master page page_load .

```
 string thisURL = this.Page.GetType().Name.ToString();       
        switch (thisURL)
        {
            case "home_aspx":
                lihome.Attributes.Add("class", "Active");                
                break;
         case "support_aspx":
                lisupport.Attributes.Add("class", "Active");
                break;
         case "logout_aspx":
                lilogout.Attributes.Add("class", "Active");
                break;
         }
```

Instead of li, use id of whatever tag you use in menu.