# ASP.NET, Master Pages and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I'm trying to create a little script to allow me to set the style of a couple of menu items (done via a simple div with li items, which contain an  each to send me to the correct page) but I'm not getting nowhere so I'm in need of help.

I have the following code on the master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="MILLS001_PAINEL.Site1" EnableTheming="True" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/menu.js"></script>
<link href="../css/reset.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if gte IE 9]>
        <style type="text/css">
            .gradient {
                filter: none;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner" class="gradient">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="painel_gestao.aspx">Painel de Gestão</a></li>
            <li><a href="gestao_operacional.aspx">Cockpit Operacional</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Placeholder" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The menu is defined in the master page, now I have this script to add certain classes (already created in CSS) to allow me to add/remove styles to the menu items:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('menu').find('li').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("hovered");
    },
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass("hovered");
    });

    $('menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
        alert(e);
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
 });
```

For some reason, I can't make this to work although I do not see any errors.
I had a problem with another script in which I had to reference names by using '[id$=name]', because Master page name mangling creates that problem, but it doesn't seem to be the case here...

Could anyone help me see what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance

#### EDIT

Got the hover thing working, but now I can't make to seem the active class to stay in place after the page refresh (apparently, a default behaviour of ASP).

Comment: I think your primary objective is to change the class of li to active on navigation. Since you use asp.net you can refer this link to achieve your goal. But it is in c#. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244240/change-class-of-menu-in-master-page-dynamically/15244566#15244566

Comment: Hope it solves your problem. Since am browsing from mobile. I couldn't give those steps in your thread itself. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do:

```
$('#menu') <-- note the # sign
```

in your selectors.... Otherwise it looks like it should work OK

API Reference: [jQuery ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

To address your edit:

Element state is not automatically preserved between page loads. The browser doesn't look for "the same element" and try to make it appear the same. If you want the menu to remain open, you need to persist some data (whether through postback data or (I would recommend) some browser side state saving (e.g. `localStorage`)) and handle it manually in your menu code

Oh....rereading your question I think it might be simpler than that....

On page load, you could do something like:

```
$('[href=' + window.location.path + ']').addClass('active');
```

the `window.location.path` would likely need some pre-processing before the selector though to handle extra url parameters and variations of the path (e.g. `./index.html` and `index.html`) in the href. However, note the various types of matching available with the attribute selector...namely `*=`...might make your href matching a lot easier...but I'm not gonna write all your code =0D

API Reference: [jQuery Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, and now I feel dumb as a door lol ('-_-)

Comment: @Zed_Blade: No worries, sometimes all you need is another pair of eyes... And I've done the exact same thing to myself ;)

Comment: I've seen it and I think you are correct. I don't need you to write my code, I'm just new to both asp and jquery :)

Comment: @Zed_Blade: I didn't think you were, I was just giving you a lot of options for how to handle it and while I like writing example code, it would have started getting pretty long :D

Answer (score 2):

Your selector looks incorrect, looks like your missing the # which notes it's an ID. Should be:

```
  $('#menu').find('a').click()
```

And a slightly different approach:

```
 $('#menu a').click()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've edited my question to reflect my new problem if you could help :)